# ContentVersion Content-Type

Tags: files, contentversion, contenttype

I need to stream a file from Salesforce in our webapplication. To make sure the file is properly opened, I have to set Content-Type header.

How to retrieve the Content-Type (MIME) of a file?

I expect values like: `image/png`, `application/pdf`, `text/html` etc.

How to get these values? I am using the Java and a SOAP client to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `ContentVersion` and `ContentDocument` objects don't store MIME types. They do, however, store a `FileType`, which contains strings like "WORD_X", "PDF", and "POWER_POINT_X", which you could potentially map to MIME types. ("UNKNOWN" is also one value for this field).

Additionally, the original file's `FileExtension` is stored on these objects and could be mapped in your code to a relevant MIME type.

Comment: Is there some place where there would be a list of possible values?

Comment: @zaitsman Not that I am aware of. It's a String field and I've never seen documentation of the slate of available values.

Comment: not like it's an extensive list, but at least some are here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_fileuploadanddownloadsecuritysettings.htm