# Getting ContentType for ContentDocuments?

Tags: rest-api, attachment, files, contentversion, contentdocument

The ContentDocument and the ContentDocumentVersion do not store a ContentType (MIME) like attachments did.

I am trying to pass documents using an API and this information is needed to properly pass the information.

Since there could, theoretically, be an infinite amount of different ContentTypes, is there a way to get this information, rather than having to build a switch statement for anything that I think might be stored in Salesforce?

Answer (score 3):

See [ContentVersion Content-Type](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/209214/102). You can manually map to a Mime type from the `FileType`.

Otherwise, consider voting for the idea [ContentVersion should have same ContentType as Document](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bG2hAAE)